# Accessing parameters when the function expects none Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, parameters

I am writing a Javascript function to count the number of instances of an element in an unsorted array. It has a method signature like this

```
Array.prototype.numberOfOccurrences = function() { 

}
```

Here is an example of expected behavior

```
var arr = [4, 0, 4];
Test.assertEquals(arr.numberOfOccurrences(4), 2);
```

My problem is that I don't know how to access the elements in the array. The function doesn't take any parameters so how do I reference the array being passed in?

Note: The instructions aren't very descriptive for this kata on code wars and adding a parameter to the function returns some error unexpected token.

Comment: Side note, you shouldn't modify objects you don't own: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/

Comment: I shouldn't modify the function by adding a parameter or I shouldn't add to the prototype chain?

Comment: You shouldn't add it to the prototype chain. In case any default implementation comes out it would break, etc. The MDN has a good article on why it's bad practice but I can't seem to find it at the moment.

Comment: Found it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Bad_practice.3A_Extension_of_native_prototypes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you should extend javascript base objects aside, `this` is your friend:

```
Array.prototype.numberOfOccurrences = function(valueToFind) { 
    return this.filter(function(item) {
        return item === valueToFind;
    }).length;
}
var a = [1,2,3,3,3,3];
console.log(a.numberOfOccurrences(3)); //4
```

As noted above, if you're not able to change the function signature for whatever reason you can specify it as follows:

```
Array.prototype.numberOfOccurrences = function() { 
    var valueToFind = arguments[0];
...
}
```

I would recommend adding the parameter to the function for clarities sake. Seems counter intuitive for a function like `numberOfOccurences` to not take in a parameter - `numberOfOccurences` of what?

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/g82b3f98/

Answer (score 2):

Inside the function you are creating into the Array.prototype you can access all the prototype functions through the "this" keyword.

Meaning you can access the array items using numeric properties like this[0] or this[1] to a access the first and second item respectively.

You can also call functions which allows you to iterate over each item on the array, such as: forEach, filter, etc.

Please refer this page to see everything you can do with the array prototype:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype

Lastly don't forget that the JavaScript implementation varies on each browser, so a function that works on Chrome, might not work on InternetExplorer, always confirm on caniuse.com If the function you are used has the same implementation on your targets browsers.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using the locally available variable 'arguments' inside of the function.  So for example, your code might look like thsi:

```
Array.prototype.numberOfOccurrences = function() { 
  var args = arguments || {};
  var testArray, testCheck;
  if (args[0] && Array.isArray(args[0]) {
    // do something with the array that was the first argument, like:
    testArray = args[0];
    testCheck = testArray.indexOf(args[1]);
    return testCheck;
  } else {
    // do what you want to do if the function doesn't receive any arguments or the first argument
    // received isn't an array.
  }
}
```

'arguments' is always available to you inside a declared function.